# PHP get dropdown value and text

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

```
<select id="animal" name="animal">                      
<option value="0">--Select Animal--</option>
<option value="1">Cat</option>
<option value="2">Dog</option>
<option value="3">Cow</option>
</select>

if($_POST['submit'])
{
$animal=$_POST['animal'];
}
```

I have a dropdown like this. What I want, I want to get selected value and text in button submit using **PHP**. I mean if it's selected 1st one. I want to get both **1** and **Cat**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$animals = array('--Select Animal--', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Cow');
$selected_key = $_POST['animal'];
$selected_val = $animals[$_POST['animal']];
```

Use your $animals list to generate your dropdown list; you now can get the key & the value of that key.

Comment: Actually in this case, dropdown generated by database.

Comment: Generating from a database makes no difference. You can generate an array to use for your dropdown list using the values you retrieve from the database. Therefore, you have a server-side array to use to create the dropdown, you can get the POSTED value and map it to the key in the array which maps back to the database id.

Answer (score 18):

Is there a reason you didn't just use this?

```
<select id="animal" name="animal">                      
  <option value="0">--Select Animal--</option>
  <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="Cow">Cow</option>
</select>

if($_POST['submit'] && $_POST['submit'] != 0)
{
   $animal=$_POST['animal'];
}
```

Comment: Never repeat the option's text as the `value` attribute -- it is needless markup bloat.  There is never any benefit to this redundancy.  Form submissions and javascript will know what you mean when you ask it for the value but there is no value attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to save the relationship on the server side. The value is the only part that is transmitted when the form is posted. You could do something nasty like...

<option value="2|Dog">Dog</option>

Then split the result apart if you really wanted to, but that is an ugly hack and a waste of bandwidth assuming the numbers are truly unique and have a one to one relationship with the text.

The best way would be to create an array, and loop over the array to create the HTML. Once the form is posted you can use the value to look up the text in that same array.

Comment: thanks for this answer. But in here I post a sample only. Actually in my case I generated this dropdown using DB. And another case is If I didn't insert this text to that particular table, I should have to join 3 tables when I showing data.

Answer (score 1):

you can make it using js file and ajax call. while validating data using js file we can read the text of selected dropdown

```
$("#dropdownid").val();   for value
$("#dropdownid").text(); for selected value
```

catch these into two variables and take it as inputs to ajax call for a php file

```
$.ajax 
   ({
     url:"callingphpfile.php",//url of fetching php  
     method:"POST", //type 
     data:"val1="+value+"&val2="+selectedtext,
     success:function(data) //return the data     
     {
```

}

and in php you can get it as

```
    if (isset($_POST["val1"])) {
    $val1= $_POST["val1"] ;
}

if (isset($_POST["val2"])) {
  $selectedtext= $_POST["val1"];
}
```