# I want to save drop down list selected text to database in php . instead of selected text its value 2 getsave

Tags: php, database

```
   <select name="Industry"  id="Industry" >
      <option value="">Select Industry</option>
      <option value="2">Account/Finance</option>
      <option value="3">Advertising</option>
     .
     .
   </select>
  <select name="Functional_Area" id="Functional_Area">
    <option value="">Select Functional Area</option>
  </select>

Drop down list Industry and Fucntional_Area get values from database ie.industry_id and            industry_name..ids as you know 1,2,3,4 and respective names .
```

when I try to save ddl selected text to database It's id value example 2 get saved to database

php code:

```
  $Industry=mysql_escape_string($_POST['Industry']);
  $insert_query=("INSERT INTO profile_experience_info (industry) values  ($Industry)");
  mysqli_query($conn,$insert_query);
```

I am a ASP.NET developer where I use to use ddl.Selectedtext property to save selected text to database but i am not getting how to do this in php .. i tried a lot and also donot want to change id's value to match option value which I mostly found on google ,
eg) I don't want to do this as in my project I have lot of ddl whos db is ready with tons of data..

```
<select name="Industry"  id="Industry" >
    <option value="">Select Industry</option>
    <option value="Account/Finance">Account/Finance</option>
    <option value="Advertising">Advertising</option>
        .
        .
</select>
```

plz suggest some another solution to save user selected text to db
Please help me in this 
Thk in advance ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670002/php-get-dropdown-value-and-text look though this link

Answer (score 0):

What i understand is that you want to save the text (Account/Finance) instead of 2 which u have given in value... for that u just need to put that text in place of value

```
<select name="Industry"  id="Industry" >
  <option value="Industry">Select Industry</option>
  <option value="Account/Finance">Account/Finance</option>
  <option value="Advertising">Advertising</option>
 .
 .
```

> hope this will work

Comment: But rohit I cannot put text in place of value becoz , in my project i have many ddl and for all dropdownlist , gets its value and text from database and database is ready with tons of values and it is not feasible to change all that......If posible put give some other suggession.......thks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected option text by using jquery something like this

```
$("#controlId option:selected").text()
```