# dynamic down list json probem with value name

Tags: json, jquery-selectors, dropdown

I have this script in json ... it works fine .... the only problem I have is that when I go to write in my db, it inserts the IDs and not the NAMES of the select .... how can I do? can you help me?  thank you all

example my code_json

```
[
 {
  "id":"1",
  "name":"TRAFILE",
  "parent_id":"0"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"2",
  "name":"MESCOLATORI",
  "parent_id":"0"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"3",
  "name":"RICOTTURA",
  "parent_id":"0"
 }, 
  {
  "id":"4",
  "name":"FINISSASGGIO",
  "parent_id":"0"
 }

 ]
```

```js
SCRIPT

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_json_data('reparto');

 function load_json_data(id,parent_id)
 {
  var html_code = '';
  $.getJSON('reparto_linea_macchina.json', function(data){

   html_code += '<option value="">Select '+id+'</option>';
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
    if(id == 'reparto')
    {
     if(value.parent_id == '0')
     {
      html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
     }
    }
    else
    {
     if(value.parent_id == parent_id)
     {
      html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
     }
    }
   });
   $('#'+id).html(html_code);
  });

 }

 $(document).on('change', '#reparto', function(){
  var reparto_id = $(this).val();
  if(reparto_id != '')
  {
   load_json_data('linea', reparto_id);
  }
  else
  {
   $('#linea').html('<option value="">Select linea</option>');
   $('#macchina').html('<option value="">Select macchina</option>');
  }
 });
 $(document).on('change', '#linea', function(){
  var linea_id = $(this).val();
  if(linea_id != '')
  {
   load_json_data('macchina', linea_id);
  }
  else
  {
   $('#macchina').html('<option value="">Select macchina</option>');
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

```html
INDEX.PHP

</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle">Reparto:</td>  
              <td align="left"><select name="reparto" id="reparto">
                <option value>Select reparto</option>
              </select></td>  
       </tr>  
       <tr>  
              <td align="left" valign="middle">Linea/Impianto:</td>
              <td align="left"><select name="linea" id="linea">
    <option value="">Select linea</option></td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle">Macchina:</td>  
              <td align="left"><select name="macchina" id="macchina">
    <option value="">Select macchina</option></td>  
       </tr>  
 
 .......
```

Comment: I see a couple of `<select>` tags that never get closed.

Comment: "_it inserts the IDs and not the NAMES of the select_"  That is what `value` attributes in the `<option>` tags do.  If you don't want them, don't declare the `value` attributes.  Done.  However, generally, good database designs prefer to save numeric/id values for easier maintenance and performance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20949609/2943403

Comment: `<option value="">Select macchina</option></td>` - invalid nesting of elements.

Comment: I only entered a part of the index.php code ...

the script is whole ... and the json file is repetitive.

Ok what is needed to insert the Ids and not the Names ... but if I wanted to write the names of all 3 select in my DB, how can I do? I don't know json well ... thank you very much

Comment: sorry, no help?