# PHP get value from Drop down list

Tags: php, html

[PHP get dropdown value and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670002/php-get-dropdown-value-and-text)

Hi I was following this post in the link above to get the users selected option from the drop down list and to do something depending on which is selected. I have a input box for the user to type a message and a drop down list of colors and if the user clicks on a certain color, it will take the users message and change it to that color but can't seem to work.

```
<select name="color" id="color">
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Here is the post

```
 if($_POST['red'] = 'red' )
{
    echo "<font color ='red'> Hi $name </font><br />";
} elseif ($_POST['submit'] = 'green')
{
    echo "<font color ='green'> Hi $name </font><br />";
} elseif ($_POST['submit'] = 'blue')
{
     echo "<font color ='blue'> Hi $name </font><br />";
}
```

All it does is make the font color red, no matter which drop down option was selected. I tried a variety of different things but can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: **A:** You are assigning everywhere, instead of comparing. Also using the wrong POST arrays from the wrong name attributes.

Comment: `if($_POST['red'] = 'red')` is not the same as `if($_POST['red'] == 'red')`

Comment: Side note, the `<font>` element went away a loooong time ago.

Comment: Plus, you've no form tags and method.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Most likely, this is not all the code related. See the `$name` variable. I suspect this is quite the partial code.

Comment: @JClaspill Too many unknowns, not to mention syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the field you're `POST`ing:

```
<select name="color" id="color">
  ...
</select>
```

When accessing the `$_POST` array, you're not looking for the value that gets posted, you're looking for the field, which is, in this case, `color`, not `red`, `green` or `blue`.

You've got the right idea, but your `if` statement is looking for the wrong thing, and using the wrong `=` (should be `==` for comparison):

```
if($_POST['color'] == 'red'){
    echo "<span style='color:red;'>Hi ".$name."</span>";
} else if ($_POST['color'] == 'blue'){
    echo "<span style='color:blue;'>Hi ".$name."</span>";
} else if ($_POST['color'] == 'green'){
    echo "<span style='color:green;'>Hi ".$name."</span>";
}
```

Fix those errors and your code should work. Also, look into using an IDE, which would show you these errors (especially the `=` vs `==` one).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the right variable in the array.

You also need to compare `==` and not assign `=`

```
if($_POST['color'] == 'red' ) {
    echo "<font color ='red'> Hi $name </font><br />";
} elseif ($_POST['color'] == 'green') {
    echo "<font color ='green'> Hi $name </font><br />";
} elseif ($_POST['color'] == 'blue') {
     echo "<font color ='blue'> Hi $name </font><br />";
}
```

Or, as I would do it:

No `if` at all, just echo our the color.

```
echo "<font color='".$_POST['color']."'> Hi ".$name." </font><br />";
```

You can also try it as a `switch` statement:

```
switch($_POST['color']){
    case "red":
        echo "<font color='red'> Hi ".$name." </font><br />";
        break;
    case "blue":
        echo "<font color='blue'> Hi ".$name." </font><br />";
        break;
    case "green":
        echo "<font color='green'> Hi ".$name." </font><br />";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Hi ".$name."<br />";
        break;
}
```

You probably want to escape strings and such first. But that gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Change first line to:

```
if($_POST['color'] == 'red' )
```

Comment: That's just the tip of the iceberg.