# Add a subject field to PHP email form

Tags: php, html, email, contact-form

I have an email form in PHP and I want to add a subject to the body of the email:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $from = 'Camino Contact Form'; 
        $to = 'emailo@example.com'; 
        $subject = 'Message from Camino.bo ';
        $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";


// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again.</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>
```

This form submits an email with the subject "Message from Camino.bo", that's ok but I want to submit in the body of the email the value the user selects from a dropdown menu:

HTML:

```
<select name="subject" id="email_subject">
    <option value="default subject">Select a subject</option>
    <option>Product A</option>
    <option>Product B</option>
    <option>Product C</option>
</select>
```

How can I do this?
PS: the subject field in my form is optional with no validation required.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6670067/2889187

Answer (score 1):

Your variables are a bit mixed up.  The 4th parameter of the `mail()` function is not 'From', it is 'Email Headers', which can be any number of header values in the correct format, each separated with a new line.  The 'From' will just be one of those headers..

```
$to = 'you@youremailaddress.com';

$subject = 'My Email Subject';

$body = 'The body text of your email....';

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
            "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n".
            "From: YOU <your@email.com>\r\n";
            // and others as required

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Add your POSTed options to the `$body` tag as required

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but in your HTML, you want to add values to the remainder of your options:

```
<select name="subject" id="email_subject">
    <option value="default subject">Select a subject</option>
    <option value="Product A">Product A</option>
    <option value="Product B">Product B</option>
    <option value="Product C">Product C</option>
</select>
```

Then your PHP could be as follows:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'Camino Contact Form <youremailaddress@domain.com>'; 
    $to = 'emailo@example.com'; 
    $subject = 'Message from Camino.bo ';
    $select_subject = $_POST['subject'];

    $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message: $message\n Subject: $select_subject";

    $headers = "From: " . $from;


    // If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
            $result='<div class="success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again.</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Notice that I've added `$select_subject` and added it to your email $body variable. Also please replace 'youremailaddress@domain.com' with the FROM email address you wish to use.

Also, I don't know if you already handle this elsewhere in your code, but I think you should display a message to screen if either `$errName`, `$errEmail` or `$errMessage` evaluate to true. Right now, if either one of those is true (assuming the code you pasted here is complete) your end user would get nothing displayed on their screen upon form submission and they might be confused by what happened and try to resubmit.