# PHP I need to get the numerical value="" and what the user sees

Tags: php, html, forms

So I'm using a form with the POST method and I have no trouble getting the value="" of the option chosen by the user. Got my math working and everything, no problem. Then I'm going over everything and realized that I need to show the user their Dilution Ratio, for example 1:1, based on what they chose.

```
<select name="yourDilution" id="yourDilution">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="2">1:1</option>
<option value="3">1:2</option>
<option value="4">1:3</option>
<option value="5">1:4</option>
```

So how do I get that done?
Thank you for your time.
Oh and please no .js, that language and I aren't currently on speaking terms.

Comment: If you need the ratio as the value client-side, why not just pass it as a value? `<option value="1:1">1:1</option>`?

Comment: Or on your PHP side check the value of `$_POST['yourDilution']` and if it equals 2, then set a variable to '1:1', or if it equals 3, then set a variable to '1:2',...

Comment: I need the value to be 2 if the ratio is 1:1, this makes my math work.

Comment: @theBartender Then you need to check what value was passed, and use maybe `switch`/`case` to fetch the ratio. PHP will only ever know the value, and nothing more.

Comment: @j08691 - So I have 19 options in the drop down, do I have to do 19 if statements? I've never used a switch, is this a good chance to try?

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll give a switch a try. Gotta learn how eventually anyway.

Comment: @theBartender you can also use a array with all the options, than `array[$_POST['yourDilution']]`.

Comment: try `$ratio = "1:".($_POST['yourDilution']-1);`

Comment: Your server populates the dropdown with values. Your server knows (can know) which value corresponds to which ratio. Here's a start: `$ratios = [2 => '1:1', 3 => '1:2', ...];` You can use that array to build your `<select>` element *and* to look up which value corresponds to what ratio when you get it back…!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP get dropdown value and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670002/php-get-dropdown-value-and-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options:

**1 - Pass the value you need**

You can simply pass '1:1' as the value and make your form handler based on this so that it is available for outputting later.

```
<option value="1:1">1:1</option>
```

**2 - Use logical values**

You could also simply pass the defining part of the ratio. If all the ratios are 1:x then pass the value of x and know that the resulting ratio will alway be 1:x

```
<option value="1">1:1</option>
```

Then in your form handler

```
$display = "1:".$_POST['yourDilution'];
```

**3 - Use value like an ID**

Re-define the value and display value relationship in your form handler with a switch statement

```
switch($_POST['yourDilution']){
 case 2: 
     $display = "1:1";
 break;
  //etc ...
}
```

Personally, I like Option 2 since it's simple and allows you to pass the least amount of data and requires less work if the form values change. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply handle this with using a array example,

```
<?php
// Here you put your options value that you want to show the user
$array = ["1:1","1:2","1:3"];
// Here you get the selection value of the user
$postValue = 2; // in your case $_POST['yourDilution']

// here you show it to the user
print_r($array[$postValue]);

?>
```