# <select> tag not posting to MySql Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm currently working on a side project to run ticket sales. I've created a simple webpage with the basics of the info I need to collect

```
<div id="session" class="tabcontent">
    <form action="test.php"  method="post" oninput="    totalamount.value = Math.round(adult.value * 10) + Math.round(student.value * 7); changedue.value = Math.round(moneygiven.value - totalamount.value);" id="ticketform"> 
        <fieldset>
            <select name=“ticketform” id="ticketform" form="ticketform">
                <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Performance</option>
                <option value=“1“ type="number" name="showtime1">Show 1 - May 9th 2017</option>
                <option value=“2“ type="number" name="showtime2">Show 2 - May 10th 2017</option>
                <option value=“3” type="number" name="showtime3">Show 3 - May 11th 2017</option>
             </select>
            <h4>Ammount of Adults</h4>
            <input name="adult" id="adult" type="number">
            <br />
            <h4>Ammount of Students</h4>
            <input name="student" id="student" type="number">
            <br />
            <h4>Money Owed</h4>
            <output name="totalamount" id="totalamount" for="adult student"></output>
            <br />
            <h4>Money Given</h4>
            <input name="moneygiven" id="moneygiven" type="number">
            <h4>Change due</h4>
            <output name="changedue" id="changedue" for="moneyowed moneygiven"></output>
            <input type="submit" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <footer>

    </footer>
```

However I've encountered a few issues, and field that is a output and the  tag options won't be sent to my database.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root"; 
$password = "root";
$dbname = "TicketSales"; 


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$showtime=$_POST['showtime'];
$adult=$_POST['adult'];
$student=$_POST['student'];
$totalamount=$_POST['totalamount'];
$moneygiven=$_POST['moneygiven'];
$changedue=$_POST['changedue'];
// Insert data into database

$sql="INSERT INTO tickets (showtime, adult, student, totalamount, moneygiven, changedue)
VALUES
('$showtime', '$adult', '$student', '$totalamount', '$moneygiven', '$changedue')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

This is my send form. Everything is linked and anything with the input tag works without issue. How can I make it also send the select value and the outputs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP get dropdown value and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670002/php-get-dropdown-value-and-text)

Comment: Warning SQL injection!  Use prepared statements : `$conn->bind_param`

Comment: Cut up the problem. Check if you get the posted values in the first place (by checking `$_POST`). If that's not happening, the issue is in the form. If you do the entire flow and check the database, there could be a dozen steps in between that are failing.

Comment: You have `form` `id="ticketform"` and also `select` `id="ticketform"`. Fix that first and see what happens or doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

**i have find the error. also remove form attribute in select tag**

problem in this lines . it's wrong to add name in option tag and also remove type. remove this

```
<select name="ticketform" id="ticketform">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Performance</option>
        <option value=“1“>Show 1 - May 9th 2017</option>
        <option value=“2“ >Show 2 - May 10th 2017</option>
        <option value=“3”>Show 3 - May 11th 2017</option>
 </select>
```

and finally get this in PHP like

```
$showtime=$_POST['ticketform'];
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but I'm still getting this error from my console [09-Oct-2017 09:05:22 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ticketform in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testPages/test/test.php on line 14

Comment: what is your select tag name?

Comment: <select name=“ticketform” id="ticketform" form="ticketform"> I set everything to ticketform so this should be the name

Comment: i have update my answer the problem i mention in answer

Comment: still won't work correctly. just sends a 0 in the place

Answer (score 0):

you are using POST method so whenever form get submitted $_POST array sets which uses element name as key and value within element as value for that key.

So as you are using `name=“ticketform”` $_POST will be set as `$_POST['ticketform'] = selected_value`

```
<select name=“ticketform” id="ticketform" >
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Performance</option>
        <option value=“1“>Show 1 - May 9th 2017</option>
        <option value=“2“ >Show 2 - May 10th 2017</option>
        <option value=“3”>Show 3 - May 11th 2017</option>
 </select>

$showtime=$_POST['ticketform'];
```