# PHP code for Drop Down menu on contact form with specific email based on choice

Tags: php

I am working on a contact form for someone and they want a drop down menu added that based off of what they choose on that menu, is where the form will go.

Example: 
Drop down Menu options are:

***General Inquiry*** goes to anyone@123.com

***Press*** goes to bored@123.com

***Booking*** goes to help@123.com

I have no idea how to set the PHP up for this.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too broad for SO. I'm sure you can find some examples when searching for "php dropdown menu" or "php select". Like in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670002/php-get-dropdown-value-and-text

Comment: We are happy to help if you encounter a more specific problem!

Comment: what do you mean by set the php?

Answer (score 1):

better way would be using Javascript and adding an eventlistener on change of the drop down menu where it will take you to the link

```
<select id="select">
  <option value="google.com">Google.com</option>
</select>

<script>
 const select = document.querySelector('#select')
 select.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
   window.location.href = select.value;

 }
</script>
```

something like this